# Paypal Rest API SDK v2

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Paypal recommends using their v2 version of the rest API for Orders and Payments processing. Their documentation is written as per the v2 APIs.

The SDK for V2 APIs is called Checkout SDK:
https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK

I need to integrate both normal and recurring payments via Paypal. It seems that the Checkout SDK does not support recurring payments APIs(CreatePlan and CreateBillingAgreement).

Do I need to include both v1(Rest API SDK) and v2(Checkout SDK) for the same if I need to use v2 APIs for orders and payments flows?

As far as I have checked there are no v2 APIs for Billing Plans and Billing Agreements for recurring payments. Is there a way I can integrate with a single SDK, may be a wrapper SDK for both v1 and v2 integration?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the beta version: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/tree/2.0-beta

More details about: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/issues/371