# PHP PayPal SDK V2 GetExpressCheckoutDetails Equivalent

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, integration

I'm trying to move our Paypal PHP integration over to utilise the latest SDK v2.

Our current NVP setup only requires 2 paypal methods

- SetExpressCheckOut

  - return transaction token ( EC-825147XXXXXXXXXXX )
- GetExpressCheckoutDetails

  - return token & PayerID ( PayerID: MYT3NHXXXXXX )

I've managed to update the first method "SetExpressCheckout" method, 
which now looked like this..

```
$token = $paypal->SetExpressCheckOut($products, $charges);
echo json_encode( array('token'=>$token ) );
```

only 2 lines, which took an array of our products & any other shipping/handling charges & returned the transaction Token, but the new method is crazy, which just returns the same Transaction ID....

```
$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setTotal($cartTotal);
$amount->setCurrency('GBP');

$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);

$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error")
                     ->setCancelUrl("https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/error");

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent('authorize')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

try {
        // $apiContext, set within our bootstrap file
        $payment->create($apiContext); 

        // need to dig through the response 'approval_url'
        // Locate token in links array, 
        // object "rel" == "approval_url":
        /*
        {
              "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "rel": "approval_url",
              "method": "REDIRECT"
        }
        */
        // looking for token: EC-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        $res_data = json_decode($payment, true);
        $urlInfo  = parse_url($res_data['links'][1]['href']);
        parse_str($urlInfo['query'], $queryParams);

        // PASS THE TOKEN BACK TO JS FILE
        echo json_encode( 
                array(
                    'token'=>$queryParams['token'], 
                    'id' => $res_data['id'] 
                ) 
            );              
}
catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    // Print detailed information on the exception.
    // HELPFUL FOR DEBUGGING
    echo $ex->getData();
}
```

but trying to replicate the old GetExpressCheckoutDetails to return the payerID is proving problematic.

My old GetExpressCheckoutDetails method looked like this..

```
$cartTotal = Context::getContext()->cart->getOrderTotal(true);              
echo json_encode($paypal->GetExpressCheckoutDetails($cartTotal));
/*
return(
   'res'     => 'Success'
   'token'   => 'EC-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
   'payerID' => 'MYT3NHXXXXXX'
)
*/
```

2 lines of code & it was done!..

but I've tried various combinations trying to get the same return value with no success & searched around for a suitable replacement for this old method.

[paypal-rest-api-still-lacking-an-equivalent-of-getexpresscheckoutdetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910936/is-paypal-rest-api-still-lacking-an-equivalent-of-getexpresscheckoutdetails)

[paypal-rest-api-sdk-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223382/paypal-rest-api-sdk-v2)

If anyone can shed some light on how to return the payerID after the payment has been captured would be great!..

Many Thanks

Marty

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to make it simple, the following method will be called as return url after payment

```
public function paypal_success(){

    $payment = Payment::get($_REQUEST['paymentId'], $this->_api_context);
    $paymentExecution = new \PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution();

    $paymentExecution->setPayerId($_REQUEST['PayerID']);
    $payment->execute($paymentExecution, $this->_api_context);

    //var_dump($_REQUEST);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($payment);
    exit;
}
```

It will be using two classes of PayPal SDK:

1. Payment Object
2. Payment Execution

It will eventually give all the details about payer. The definition of `$this->_api_context` is:

```
$this->_api_context = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential("CLIENT_ID", "SECRET")
    );
```

Please let me know if you need any further explanation.